# Inheriting from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, user-interface, expression-blend

I'm trying to go trough [this tutorial](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/11/01/LongListSelector.aspx?Page=1) and there's  [related code](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/01/longlistselector/listing1.aspx) to it.
This part

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return Items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

gives me an error

```
"Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments"
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the error is specifically related to that part?  The example has the class inheriting from IEnumerator<T> and implements the method `public IEnumerator <T> GetEnumerator()`.  Does your code have that too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *inherit* from *IEnumerable*.  That is an interface.  You can implement interfaces.

The error message you show leads me to suspect that you are implementing `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` which returns `IEnumerator` (a non-generic interface) but attempting to use the generic, `IEnumerator<T>` interface in your code.

The code in your link indeed shows the implementation of a generic interface

```
public IEnumerator <T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: In that code there's already the method you wrote (public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()). But there is also method "IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()" which I was talking about and which is causing problems. Anyway, I deleted it, but now there's an error "PhoneApp1.Group<T> does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'PhoneApp1.Group<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'" because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'. What should I do?

Comment: Before you removed the code, where *exactly* did you see that error?  What line of code is the error in reference to?  The error message seems to be complaining about where you *reference* GetEnumerator(), not where you define it.